# Add custom data to products and load custom template for products Shopify

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I am new at shopify, so i am really stuck in this.

I need to add a custom field for price, lets call it `wholesale_price`, this `wholesale_price` is `optional` and is to be used when the user select more than `x` products (where `x` is constant) in the `item_quantity` box, else it would use the default `item price`.

For example, i have a products called `shirt`, it `price` is `100$`, but i would like to add a `wholesale_price` for `50$`, so if the customer select in the `item_quantity` more that `6` (`x = 6`) the price that will be added to the cart is `50$` each, and not `100$`.

It is possible?
If it is posible, can i add that field to the creation product window?
If not theres a way to add the field programatically? or in a json file?
Is there an app that can help with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved with and without an APP.

#### Method 1 without an APP:

You have to create two variants for the product.

1) first will be $100

2) second will be $50

Each time the user adds the item in the cart you will have to check the quantity in the cart. If it reaches 6 you will have to remove the $100 variant and change it with the $50 variant.

There will be a quite JS logic here since you will have to take in consideration if the user updates the cart and try to buy 5 afterwards and you will have to swap the variant to the $100 once again.

#### Method 2 with an APP:

You can use an APP such as https://apps.shopify.com/special-offers which allows to do what you are looking for without any additional code.